# Exibit an atlas on $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I have to exibit an atlas for the two dimensional torus $T^2$. The hint was $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1 $. So i tried to exibit an atlas made of 4 charts:

$A = \{(U_S, \phi_S), (U_N, \phi_N), (U'_S, \phi'_S), (U'_N, \phi'_N) \}$

where those charts are the ones that covers the one-sphere of radius R, $S^1(R)$, (the charts labeled without ') and the ones that covers $S^1(r)$ (the charts labeled with '), $ r < R$ (e.g. $R = 1$, $r = \frac{8}{9}$). Pratically i'm considering stereographic projections.

Is it right?

Comment: Can we use a square and then expontiate?

Comment: What is relevant about these $r$ and $R$? I removed some tags which were not accurate.

Answer (score 3):

If your atlas for $\mathbb{S}^1$ is $\mathcal{A}=\{(U_1,\varphi_1), (U_2,\varphi_2)\}$, you can get a smooth structure on your product manifold $T=\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$ by simply considering the atlas

$$
\mathcal{B}=\{(U_1\times U_1, \phi_1 \times \phi_1), (U_2\times U_2, \phi_2 \times \phi_2), (U_1\times U_2,\phi_1\times \phi_2), (U_2\times U_1,\phi_2\times\phi_1)\}.
$$

This can be generalized to any finite product of smooth manifolds. It is a good exercise to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a well defined atlas.

Comment: You forgot to consider $(U_1\times U_2,\phi_1\times \phi_2)$ and $(U_2\times U_1,\phi_2\times\phi_1)$. The corresponding atlas on $T^n$ has $2^n$ charts, not $2$ charts!

Comment: Of course! Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me, why do we have a smooth structure in this way?
So mine idea was wrong?
Furthermore I haven't understood who $U_i$ and $\phi_i$ are

Comment: @AlessandroMollicone They correspond to your $(U_N,\phi_N)$ and $(U_S,\phi_S)$. The idea is the following: if you have a smooth atlas on $M$, say $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha\in A}$, and a smooth atlas on $N$, say $\{(V_{\beta},\psi_{\beta})\}_{\beta\in B}$, then $\{(U_{\alpha}\times V_{\beta},\phi_{\alpha}\times\psi_{\beta})\}_{(\alpha,\beta)\in A\times B}$ is a smooth atlas on $M\times N$. Jotabeta just took $M=N=S^1$ with a smooth atlas consisting in two charts (for instance, the stereographic atlas)

Comment: Thanks, i understood.